# Add a Python package to ArcGIS

Tags: python, arcgis-pro

I would like to add the following package to my Python Enviroment: https://github.com/terraformer-js/terraformer/blob/master/packages/arcgis/README.md .
I have cloned the default eviroment. Via "Add Packages" I can only add packages from the list. Pip or conda do not work in the python console either. Does anyone have any ideas or experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

By 'Cloned the default environment' your are referring to cloning the Github repository or the ArcGIS Pro Python repository.  As you may know, the Python environment in ArcPy is locked behind a walled garden.  You cannot add third-party packages to this Python interpreter.  You will need to make a clone of you Python environment.  [See the instructions here](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000020560).

Still, this will not help because your link points to a java script repository and not a Python repository.